# How to choose a foreign key in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

In the data modeler browser, I am aware there is a way to choose a foreign key in an entity, in a **foreign key properties** menu (under "associated columns").

However I'm having trouble finding this menu.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle on the relationship button in the toolbar.

Click on the parent entity, then click on the child entity. The line will be drawn AND you'll get a properties dialog for the relationship.

Or if the line is already there, simply double-click the line.